# Update table When table is grouping up and delete the same row using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

1. first question
   two columns `create table test (word varchar(255),value int);`

how can I update table when we have same `word`

for example:`<a,1> ,<b,1> , <a,1>` will   add new rows `<a,2>` and remove the two `<a,1>` rows

2.second question

How to speed up if table have hundred of  pair , and table still grouping up (still inserting),can I check it every 1 hour ? and do the update step ?

MySQL or PHP code

Comment: Your questions and tags not clear!
If your table have: `<a,1> <a,1> <a,1>`. You will add `<a,3>` then remove what?

Comment: @NguyễnHảiTriều remove all of the rows that is <a,1>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is to have a table that has *unique* values of `word`, then I wouldn't allow an insert of a row with the same word value in the first place, and just update the existing row instead.

I would enforce uniqueness of the `word` column by adding a UNIQUE KEY or PRIMARY KEY constraint.  For example:

```
  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `test_ux1` ON `test` (`word`) ;
```

If I want to disallow NULL values for `word`, I would add `NOT NULL` to the column definition. For example:

```
  ALTER TABLE `test` MODIFY `word` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ;
```

Or, I could instead define `word` to be the PRIMARY KEY for the table, rather than a UNIQUE KEY.  This will enforce uniqueness as well as disallowing NULL values.

---

And here's a demonstration of how this would work, inserting and updating rows.

We could first attempt to insert a row. In this case, the row has a value of 'a' for the `word` column:

```
  INSERT INTO `test` (`word`, `value`) VALUES ('a','1') ;
```

If the statement succeeds, we've inserted a row. But with a primary key or unique key on the `word` column, this will throw a "duplicate key" error, because a row with a value of 'a' already exists in the table.

When that happens, we know we need to perform an UPDATE of the existing row. For example:

```
  UPDATE `test` t 
     SET t.`value` = IFNULL(t.`value`,0) + '1'
   WHERE t.word = 'a'
```

MySQL provides an extension (`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement) that will perform the same operation in a single statement:

```
  INSERT INTO `test` (`word`,`value`) VALUES ('a','1')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY
  UPDATE `value` = IFNULL(`value`,0) + VALUES(`value`)
```

---

This design seems much more efficient than performing inserts, inserting rows that are later going to be undone with delete operations. I'd prefer to have just the rows I need, and not add extra rows that will need to be queried and deleted later.